# Gentoo VGA arbitration boot stuck

Tags: kernel, gentoo

I'm quite new to gentoo.
When booting my gentoo operating system it gets stuck on

```
pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decode=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
```

my first reflex was that this is a mistake in my kernel config with the graphics drivers but I couldn't find the problem there.
I undid some of my kernel changes now: I changed the amount of GPU's from 2 back to 16, I now get another error message,

```
radeon 0000:01:00.0: remove _conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar2: 0xe4000000 -> 0xe400ffff
```

why would this change when updating the number of GPU's?
I thought that 2 was enough (1 for integrated graphics and 1 for my GPU)

My laptop has a Intel Pentium U4100 and an ATI radeon HD 4330 graphics card

Thanks anyway

Comment: Is it a clean installation? How did you create your kernel .config? Did you use [genkernel](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Kernel#Alternative:_Using_genkernel) in running Gentoo live? There are many things that could go wrong if you configured your kernel manually.

Comment: @BlueManCZ It was indeed a clean installation, I created the .config as in the handbook: ```make && make modules_install``` , then ```make install```. I did my installation throught ubuntu. I did not use genkernel.

Comment: @BlueManCZ If there are so many things that could go wrong, would you reccomend going back to the default kernel settings? I did spend some time poking around in the kernel settings so it probably is a problem there. maybe I should first look for a running os and then start optimizing it.

Comment: Yes, exactly as you said. Start with genkernel and working configuration. Then before each change you backup latest working .config, make few edits, compile the kernel again and check if it works. If not, you know exactly what went wrong and you can revert your saved .config.

Comment: @BlueManCZ Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 0):

I got it up and running, for me the genkernel didn't work,
If I went in my Kernel I disabled my `ATI Radeon` And the `laptop hybrid graphics` under ---> Devices ---> Graphics

It might be one of the two or both.
When I find wich one it is I will update this answer.